# Use Vertical Steps component from antd with in a ScrollPanel from PrimeReact

Tags: reactjs, antd, primereact

I would like to use the Vertical Steps from antd(https://ant.design/components/steps/)  within a primeReact ScrollPanel(https://www.primefaces.org/primereact/#/scrollpanel). I would also like to use the "Next" and "Previous" button as shown in the "antd" example. All works fine till here, but when I have a lot of steps and the click on "Next" moves to next step but the Scroller doesn't move i.e. the highlighted step moves out of View. How to make the scroll also move so the selected Step is in centre View?

Code for vertical Steps inside ScrollPanel:

```
class VerticalStepsWithContent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { current: 0 };
  }

  next() {
    const current = this.state.current + 1;
    this.setState({ current });
  }

  prev() {
    const current = this.state.current - 1;
    this.setState({ current });
  }

  onChange = current => {
    console.log("onChange:", current);
    this.setState({ current });
  };

  render() {
    const { Step } = Steps;
    const steps = [
      {
        title: "First",
        content: "First-content"
      },
      {
        title: "Second",
        content: "Second-content"
      },
      {
        title: "Last",
        content: "Last-content"
      }
    ];
    const { current } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="steps-action">
          {current < steps.length - 1 && (
            <Button type="primary" onClick={() => this.next()}>
              Next
            </Button>
          )}
          {current === steps.length - 1 && (
            <Button
              type="primary"
              onClick={() => message.success("Processing complete!")}
            >
              Done
            </Button>
          )}
          {current > 0 && (
            <Button style={{ marginLeft: 8 }} onClick={() => this.prev()}>
              Previous
            </Button>
          )}
        </div>
        <ScrollPanel
          header="Summary"
          style={{ height: "400px" }}
          className="custom"
        >
          <Steps
            direction="vertical"
            current={current}
            onChange={this.onChange}
          >
            {steps.map(item => (
              <Step key={item.title} title={item.title} />
            ))}
          </Steps>
        </ScrollPanel>
        {/* <div className="steps-content">{steps[current].content}</div> */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default VerticalStepsWithContent;
```

Comment: Try [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't [bind class functions to `this` instance](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) (which is a common bug):

```
class VerticalStepsWithContent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { current: 0 };
    this.next = this.next.bind(this);
    // bind rest of the functions
  }
}
```

You should avoid the use of `constructor`, instead use class properties:

```
class VerticalStepsWithContent extends Component {
  state = { current: 0 };

  next = () => {
    const current = this.state.current + 1;
    this.setState({ current });
  };

  // ...
}
export default VerticalStepsWithContent;
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing, But that doesn't fix the issue, any idea on how to get the scrollPanel working. TIA